# Who is sending http websocket upgrade requests?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Websocket? Or XMLHttpRequest? Or I have to do it myself?

So I understand the client has to send it, but when and why? Suppose I use the XMLHttpRequest object to send a normal HTTP GET. 
I have no control over how long that internal tcp connection in the browser lasts, right?
And if I want to use websockets I have to use their own websocket classes anyway, so for me as a user, "upgrading" is not visible, is it? 
It's just the browser that is doing some internal magic to reuse a connection, the whole upgrade process is irrelevant for me as a user? I still have to use two different classes, I just happen to use the same port and the browser then decides for performance reasons to upgrade.
Is that really correct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, the WebSocket clients sends the HTTP request asking for a WebSocket connection, then the server responds with an HTTP 101 Switching protocols, meaning that it accepts the connection, and then the client can start to send and receive data in binary format.

Example client request:

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com
```

Example server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

It is well explained in the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake

And it is detailed in the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3

> It's just the browser that is doing some internal magic to reuse a
> connection, the whole upgrade process is irrelevant for me as a user?

That is right.

> I still have to use two different classes, I just happen to use the
> same port and the browser then decides for performance reasons to
> upgrade. Is that really correct?

If you want to use AJAX you use `XMLHttpRequest`. If you want to use WebSocket, you use the `WebSocket` class. Still, they can be accessed by the same port. The difference is that the WebSocket connection will negotiate with the server a full duplex persistent binary channel, while the `XMLHttpRequest` will just make a request and get a response.

Comment: Oh okay, so every WebSocket class sends an Http Request if it wants to send binary data. So suppose I send an http get, then open a websocket, then send a normal http get again... the browser would then have to open a new client socket because the old one is already converted to websocket and I assume it stays that way forever now and the serverside on that socket doesnt need to be able to handle http requests?

Comment: Right. Each WS connection starts always as a HTTP request. Once the WS negotiation is done through HTTP, the connection does not close, it keeps open for messaging using binary frames till it closes, no more HTTP is allowed in that channel. This HTTP negotiation mechanism is very helpful, because it allows to traverse security inspectors and does not need to map and/or open additional TCP ports in routers and firewalls; it also allows to exchange cookies, so it has a great integration into web apps.

Comment: @vtortola Is this possible for server to initiate the websocket upgrade? For example, the browser client logs in using HTTP protocol then once the server has authenticated the client, it responses with a websocket upgrade. When the client sees this response it acknowledges the connection has been upgraded to websocket so it can now communicate with the server using websocket.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Client must request the upgrade.